# eNCODING eXTREME ·(

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You're `?·*´`.

Don't ask me why.

You always have known it, or since that `¿`th.

If you know it, can you say to me why are you `?·*´`?

Is the secret behind the `€/&"` button involved? I know: No need.

*`Think it again.`[.](http://The_secret_in_the_?_is_LS1bLS0tLS0+KzxdPi0tLisuLS0tLS4rKysu)*

*`Remember that real ^´()·$ .`*

`What am I asking? What are you? That are the questions I ask.`

Hint:
`You can't read this.`

Hint 2:
`The response is also in the unsolved.`

Comment: Is it *very hard to solve* or just *new set of smileys* :-?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't, and yes if you want to, you can give hints (with increasing order of relatedness to the logic behind the answer, if any) :)

Comment: This puzzle is sooo "enigmatic" that it is not even clear what you're asking at all. Maybe add at least a real *question* at the end? Otherwise my answer is clear, it is: &^" !!!   (And proove me wrong!)

Comment: BTW, adding info in tiny, tiny locations of your puzzle might not be the best idea for all those using mobile devices to read the site.

Comment: Like BmyGuest I feel that this puzzle is unclear -- so enigmatic I don't even know what I should try to decode. And the portions of ciphertext are far too small to go on.

Comment: Looks like regex?

Comment: `Is the secret behind the €/&" button involved?` - the Euro symbol and & symbol seem to represent 5 and 7 respectively on a keyboard. http://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/pics/layout.png

Comment: Again, why the 2 downvotes? D:

Comment: One DV was from me. Retracted after your edit now.

Answer (score 3):

Incomplete answer:

> First, the secret message hidden in the link after "Think it again":
>  `the_secret_in_the_/?_is_LS1bLS0tLS0+KzxdPi0tLisuLS0tLS4rKysu`
>
> Second, `LS1bLS0tLS0+KzxdPi0tLisuLS0tLS4rKysu` is `--[----->+<]>--.+.----.+++.` in Base64.
>
> Third, `--[----->+<]>--.+.----.+++.` is Brainfuck for `dead`

Comment: Why would anyone be cruel enough to make one deal with Brainf*** encoding??